# ORDER BY id or date_created to show latest results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I have a table (several actually) that I want to get results from with the most recent entries first. Here are my `ORDER BY` clause options:

- date_created INT (never changes value)
- id (INT AUTO_INCREMENT of course!)

Both columns should equally represent the order in which the records were inserted. I naturally would use the `date_created` field like any sane person would, but I'm still curious about this.

I know this is probably splitting hairs, but is there any reason or edge case why I should NOT use the `id` column?

**EDIT:** I'm thinking that this question is vague as to which value we want to truly represent the insert order. Thank you for all your answers everybody, I am going to accept the best one and move on because I think I have made this difficult by assuming that ids will always be in order (see @Wrikken's comment). My gut instinct is that id should never be considered by the developer, which is what most of the answers here are pointing to.

Comment: What exactly do you store when `date_created` is an INT (not TIMESTAMP?!)?  The `id` column is likely the primary key, which would mean uniqueness and automatically indexed (as of MySQL 5.x IIRC) -- in that case, the better choice.

Comment: It comes down to indexing more than anything.  Can you provide the indexes (if any) on these two columns, and whether you are ordering ASC vs. DESC?

Comment: I don't understand this: `What exactly do you store when date_created is an INT (not TIMESTAMP?!)?`, can you clarify? As I said, the date_created field is INT

Comment: @OMG, it is likely a UNIX timestamp, which is seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: `id`'s are _not_ guaranteed to be in order (for instance, when transactions are involved).

Comment: @Madmartigan - If date_created is a Unix timestamp, can you be certain that no two rows are inserted in the same second?  That may normally be true, but if you've got a multi-user system, there may be duplicate dates which would introduce some arbitrariness into the sort.  Does it matter if the sort is completely deterministic?

Comment: @Madmartigan - my bad.  I did submit an answer below though, which is true regardless of any indexing or lack thereof.

Comment: Post the CREATE TABLE statement so we can see if the `date_created` column data type is INT or TIMESTAMP.  If the column is not TIMESTAMP (or DATETIME for that matter), provide what format the date value is being stored as (couple of examples would help).

Comment: @OMG Ponies: What is unclear to you? It's obvious I'm using INT if you read the post for 5 seconds.

Comment: Others are arguing that you are not, that you are using a UNIX TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: A unix timestamp **is** an integer.

Comment: I'm not arguing that, I'm wanting you to explicitly state what you are using.  Why is it so hard to get a simple answer?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The column type is INT and the values are actually UNIX timestamps. Everyone else seemed to understand perfectly. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I prefer to clarify than assume - seen a lot of weird date formats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't a good idea to depend on the ID column for time ordering, because that isn't its purpose. Basically, the ID is just a unique key for that row, nothing more. Using ID might never cause problems, but there is no reason to add complexity of assuming that ordering by ID will always hold. For instance, you might in the future want to delete entries and then manually insert new entries, or import entries from some other source that are timestamped in the past. If you didn't have a date_created column, then ID would be your only option, but since you have the column, use it, as it is your best choice.

Comment: Note: Dane's commend about indexing is also important. If you are ordering by date_created, you will want and index on this column. You probably already have an index on ID, so consider the overhead of an extra index.

Comment: By the way excellent point here: "*import entries from some other source that are timestamped in the past*" It's come up since I asked this question - we had a membership merge between two sites and ordering by id to indicate newset/oldest is now rather pointless (like date_registered).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming date_created never gets touched (you have stated that it doesn't) I think sorting by the ID column would be better in terms of performance.  Presumably the ID column is your pkey and thus already indexed.  No reason not to use it for sorting.  I know the case has been made that you should always use a date for ordering but honestly in this case I would use the ID.

Comment: This is one way how I am viewing it, possible performance increase

Comment: @Madmartigan: First off, cool name.  Second, I think that is really the only benefit you would get here but it is still one that is very much worth noting.  I would obviously default to the date sort if it were a modified or rev date (because those are obviously subject to change) but the way you describe it I would go w/ the ID.

Answer (score 4):

One good reason, as a rule - because you (or someone who inherits your app) may retroactively insert a record with a older timestamp (that is, explicitly set the timestamp to something in the past rather than the current).  You can't always rely on the ID sorting matching the timestamp sorting.

Comment: This makes sense to me, because it could really happen, but in that case it would still be true that the record was indeed created at an earlier time, therefore not the "newest".

Answer (score 3):

In general you should not rely on IDs, if you already have a field devoted to creation time. Maybe in case of collision (records created in exactly the same moment) you can use ID as a secondary order clause.

Answer (score -3):

Say you run yourself out of positive integers on the id and you change your auto increment to use negative ints.  Your order by id would not return the most recent records first.

Hey, you asked for an edge case!  ;-)

Comment: You'd probably be retired by then anyhow.  LOL