# How to select from last to first row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Whenever a query like
`"select * from table where userid=xx"` is done, the mysql fetches these values from
first row to last row of table.

But I want to select from last to first so that recently updated values are displayed first in the results.

I cannot do `"select * from table where userid=xx order by time DESC"` because there is no time column in table.
I just want recently updated items in the table displayed first.

Comment: Is there anything in the table that tracks when updates were made?

Comment: Do you have an auto-incremented id?

Comment: Can there exists a fundamental order of the rows in a database, except that which you yourself define? I don't think row order is a necessity in a database specification, though I could be wrong.

Comment: You can't guarantee an order unless you have some column value that actually indicates the order. Otherwise it's a crap shoot.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570958/order-by-id-or-date-created-to-show-latest-results

Comment: Especially if you use indexes and limit / offset

Comment: @andrewsi :no there is no such tracking system

Comment: @mathieu it is the table that stores inventoryid and merchantid so there is no indexing here..it is a table containing ids of inventory and merchant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any auto-incrementing field you could sort by that desc.

You must provide a column to order by in order to guarantee results.  So you will have to either change your table structure or make a decision on what to order by.

A hack would be to pull in the data in the order presented into an array, then start popping off the bottom of that array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT 
(SELECT column FROM table WHERE [condition] ORDER BY column LIMIT 1) as 'first',
(SELECT column FROM table WHERE [condition] ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1) as 'last'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['first'];
echo $row['last'];
```

Comment: Please provide your answer with clear descriptions. Don't write the code, give the explanation about the code which you have shared, so that others can also understand and it will be helpful. I request you to read the FAQ Section in-order to use Stack Overflow in an effective manner.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to have a timestamp, or autoincrement id, or some other column that you want to sort by.

Just because you get rows in a certain order from a database when not using an `ORDER BY` clause, does not mean that they are guaranteed to be returned in that order.  It also doesn't imply any order in the result set.  You need a definitive field that you can use to `ORDER BY`, or you cannot do what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Some hack you can do for that if you don't have columns you can rely on:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,(@x:=@x+1) default_ordering FROM `table_name`, (SELECT @x:=0) t2) any_name ORDER BY default_ordering DESC
```